# VB.NET - IF statement to check if typed key is not present in label

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

As the question says, i want to make an IF statement to check if the pressed key is not present in any of the six labels that i have created. In the six labels, a letter is randomly produced and placed into each.

I have this line of code but it doesn't work as intended as correct key presses still execute the code beneath.

```
If (e.KeyChar <> lblletter1.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter2.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter3.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter4.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter5.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter6.Text) Then
            score -= 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            incorrect += 1
        End If
```

Here is the code above this section:

```
If (e.KeyChar = lblletter2.Text) Then
            'MsgBox("works")
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter2.Top = 35
            lblletter2.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If
```

For some reason it works as intended after i disable the line, i have this repeated for each of the six labels that i have.

```
lblletter2.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
```

Hope it is not too confusing

```
 Private Sub typingtutor_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    'CHECKS IF THE KEY PRESSED IS THE SAME AS THE LETTER IN THE LABELS, IF IT IS THEN THE LABEL MAKES A NEW LETTER AND ADDS 1 TO THE SCORE
    'PROBLEM WITH CODE - IF THERE ARE TWO LABELS WITH SAME LETTER I CANNOT FIND A WAY TO CHECK TO MAKE ONE KEYPRESS CHANGE BOTH LABELS WITHOUT AFFECTING THE SCORING (TRIED SEPARATE IF STATEMENTS BUT THEN THAT MEANS THE ELSE STATEMENT CANNOT BE USED, THE CODE "e.keychar <> lblletter.text" DOESN:T WORK)

    If line1.Visible = True Then ' Disables key presses from working until the start button is pressed
        'nested if statements that work only when the above condition is met (line becomes visible when start button is pressed)
        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter1.Text) Then ' check if the pressed key (e.keychar) is the same as the letter in the label
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter1.Top = 35
            'lblletter1.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString 'uses the randomly produced number that was declared globally and converts it to a letter (ascii) - sourced from MSDN
            num = random.Next(97, 122) 'chooses a random number between 97 and 122 which represents the letters of alphabet, for next letter
            speed += 1 ' keeps track of how many key presses there are have been
        End If
        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter2.Text) Then
            'MsgBox("works")
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter2.Top = 35
            'lblletter2.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If

        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter3.Text) Then
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter3.Top = 35
            'lblletter3.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If
        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter4.Text) Then
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter4.Top = 35
            'lblletter4.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If
        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter5.Text) Then
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter5.Top = 35
            'lblletter5.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If
        If (e.KeyChar = lblletter6.Text) Then
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            lblletter6.Top = 35
            'lblletter6.Text = Convert.ToChar(num).ToString
            num = random.Next(97, 122)
            speed += 1
        End If
        'Else
        'If (e.KeyChar <> lblletter1.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter2.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter3.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter4.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter5.Text And e.KeyChar <> lblletter6.Text) Then
        If (e.KeyChar <> lblletter1.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter2.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter3.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter4.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter5.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter6.Text(0)) Then
            'If (e.KeyChar <> lblletter1.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter2.Text(0) And _
            'e.KeyChar <> lblletter3.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter4.Text(0) And _
            'e.KeyChar <> lblletter5.Text(0) And e.KeyChar <> lblletter6.Text(0)) Then
            score -= 1
            lblscore.Text = score
            incorrect += 1 ' variable used to check for accuracy
            speed += 1
            Label2.Text = incorrect
        End If
    End If

    If score < 0 Then
        counter -= 1
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have to worry about capitalization?

Comment: Try using `AndAlso` instead of `And`.

Comment: What do you mean by "if there are two labels with the same letter, I cannot find a way to check to make one KeyPress change both labels without affecting the scoring"? What is supposed to happen when two labels contain the same letter?

Comment: What i wanted to do was find a way to change more than one label at once. Eg theres 2 labels containing "m", i want to find a way to change both labels by pressing m once. However when i coded the above to do so, it affected the scoring by not increasing it when a correct letter was typed. What happens is that it increases the score by one but then also decreases by one, so it stays the same. The only way that the score increases is if i either disable the command "convert.tochar(num)" which would stop the letters from randomising or if i type a letter that appears in at least two labels.

Comment: So if two labels contain "m" and the user types "m", both labels should get a new random letter. What about the score, does it increase by 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes the score should increase by 2

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit] 
This answer has been updated to respond to changes in the question.

Rather than duplicating the code for each of the 6 labels, it is easier to create an array of labels and loop through the array. In order to keep everything together, I have created the array KeyPress event. It would be better to make the array a Private field in the form and initialise it in the form's Load event. The code uses a boolean value called `good` to remember if the key pressed matches any of the labels.

```
Sub MainForm_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim labels() As Label = {lblletter1, lblletter2, lblletter3, lblletter4, lblletter5, lblletter6}
    If Not line1.Visible Then Exit Sub 
    speed += 1

    Dim good As Boolean 
    For Each lab As Label In labels
        If e.KeyChar = lab.Text(0) Then
            score += 1
            lblscore.Text = score.ToString 
            lab.Top = 35
            Dim num As Integer = random.Next(97, 123) 'choose >= "a" And < "{"
            lab.Text = Chr(num)
            good = True 
        End If
    Next

    If Not good Then
        score -= 1
        lblscore.Text = score.ToString 
        incorrect += 1
        Label2.Text = incorrect.ToString 
        If score < 0 Then counter -= 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It still doesn't work :(, even when the keypress is correct it subtracts the current score that i have

Comment: It worked in my test case. What are the contents of the labels and what did you type? Also, is this code in the Form's KeyPress event handler (with KeyPreview set to True)?

Comment: Yes keypreview is set to true, the labels have 1 letter in them. I am typing the letters that are shown in the labels but even when I type a correct letter it still executes the command.

Comment: All I can say is that it works for me. I suggest running in the debugger and set a breakpoint on the If statement. Then type one of the letters from a label. When execution stops at the breakpoint. check the values of `e.KeyChar` and the label's text. Perhaps make things simpler by changing the If to only check one label, then if that works check two labels.

Comment: It turns out that i had a line of code that was stuffing everything up, not sure why though. Would you be able to check it out? I've included it in the bottom part of my original question.

Comment: Would you be able to explain what the 0 in lab.text(0) does? Also for the part that you commented out, what did you mean by that?

Comment: @BustinJieber We are comparing a Char `e.KeyChar` to a String `lab.Text`. This works because the compiler automatically converts the Char to a String before comparing. Those automatic conversions can sometimes cause problems (although not in this case) and I am in the habit of doing the conversion myself. As a String can be treated as an array of Char, lab.Text(0) returns the first Char in the array.

Comment: @BustinJieber The comment on the use of `Random` really was a comment and not code. I was noting that `random.Next(97, 123)` will select from the letters "a" - "z". the second argument is not the last number that can be selected, it is the first number that **cannot** be selected. You hace coded `random.Next(97, 122)` which would only select from "a" - "y".

Comment: Oh thanks for picking that up, i hadn't noticed that. Thanks for your help, you are a lifesaver